# Vbcr, vbNewLine in resx file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have placed large text in resx file. The text contains `Vbcr, VbNewLine` for formatting options. When i display the text in label, it don't get formatted. How i format the text. I am using visual studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoSize to true and play with the MaximumSize property of the label.